# Compose key keeps coming back. How to disable it permanently?

Tags: keyboard

Recently, I attached an aluminium USB Apple keyboard to my Thinkpad running Ubuntu 20.04, setting Compose to Caps using `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`.

Now I cannot get my old Left Win / Super keys behaviour back.

I'm manually setting the keyboard layout using `setxkbmap -option "" -variant "" -layout "de" -model "pc105"` multiple times a day (probably every time the laptop suspended) and I'm out of ideas where else the system could get the undesired setting.

This is the config

**/etc/default/keyboard** (that's what I want!):

```
XKBLAYOUT="de"
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBOPTIONS=""
```

`setxkbmap -query`: completely puzzled about this. Keyboard behaves like a pc105 alright, not sure where the `variant: ,mac,,` comes from and most importantly: lwin shouldn't be Compose.

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     de,de,gb,gb
variant:    ,mac,,
options:    compose:lwin,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
```

The **Ubuntu keyboard layout** view agrees with the settings returned by `setxkbmap -query`:
[image: Keyboard layout showing lwin as Compose]

**Gnome Tweaks** says the Compose key is **Disabled**:

[image: Gnome Tweak screenshot]

I do **not** have an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`.

Pointers on where to look for persisted settings much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps something set in Gnome: what does `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` say? You cannot "reset" running `dpkg-reconfigure` again (you didn´t mention any attempt in that direction).

Comment: @vanadium `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options` returns "['compose:lwin', 'terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp']", in line with what the Gnome keyboard layout widget shows.

I am able to (temporarily) change my keyboard layout back using dpkg-reconfigure, but that a) takes a long time and b) doesn't last.

Answer (score 0):

After having been pointed to `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-source xkb-options` in [Compose key keeps coming back. How to disable it permanently?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1359592/compose-key-keeps-coming-back-how-to-disable-it-permanently#comment2329274_1359592), I was able to `gsettings set`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options "[]"
```

So far, the settings stick and I am able to reliably use the Gnome keyboard layout switcher to change between keyboard layouts.

[image: keyboard switcher tray]